# Time evolution operator of a periodic Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter

Suppose we have a Hamiltonian $H(t)$ with periodicity $T$. The time evolution operator in a full period is $$U_1=\cal{T}e^{-i\int_0^T H(t)\mathrm{d}t},$$ where $\cal{T}$ is time ordering operator; similarly, the time evolution operator in two periods is $$U_2=\cal{T}e^{-i\int_0^{2T} H(t)\mathrm{d}t}.$$

**My question is, whether the relation $U_2=U_1U_1$ holds?**

I am asking this because in [this paper](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.82.235114), equation (5), the author introduce an effective Hamiltonian $H_{\rm eff}$ by $$U_1=\exp(-iH_{\rm eff}T)$$
and claim that we can effectively describe the evolution of system using the effective static Hamiltonian $H_{\rm eff}$ period by period. So I conjure the above relation should hold for this approximation.

In case that I've misunderstood the author's intention, I'll quote their statement:

> When viewed in this way, evolution under the periodically
>   varying Hamiltonian $H(t)$ stroboscopically simulates the
>   evolution of a system with a static Hamiltonian $H_{\rm eff}$ at integer multiples of the driving period T.

Comment: The answer is yes. $U_2 = U_1 U_1$. You can prove it. Furthermore writing $U_1$ as an exponential of an effective Hamiltonian is not an approximation, any unitary can be written like as an exponential of $i$ times a Hermitian operator. So the equation defines the effective Hamiltonian.

Comment: @nervxxx A stupid question, I realized this relation is true as soon as I sat down having my lunch. Thanks for the comment. I agree that the second equation is not an approximation, you can always find an $H_{eff}$ satisfies that. However, describing the original system using the static Hamiltonian is definitely an approximation, even in the period by period manner, do you think so?

Comment: Which static Hamiltonian do you mean? You can find $H_{eff}$ by solving the Dyson series for the evolution operator (or a Magnus expansion), and you can truncate the series at some order to get an approximation. But let's say that you manage to find $H_{eff}$ exactly. Then if you view the system in stroboscopic time (periods of $T$), the system looks exactly like it involves under the static Hamiltonian $H_{eff}$, that's not an approximation.